# Is there graphical support for scribbling on a canvas in the nana c++ as in MFC?

Tags: c++, c++11, mfc, nana

I had an old graphic application written in MFC of VC6 that I am trying to migrate to a more standard compliant C++ framework. I looked at the documentation of the nana project [here](https://github.com/qPCR4vir/nana-docs/wiki/Examples), trying to find a basic example for scribbling on a canvas-like widget similar to the old [scribble MDI drawing example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92y4h944%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that's shipped with Visual C++.

I read that nana is a new promising c++ GUI platform and I am wondering whether it is good for general GUI programming. Looking at the nana documentation, however, there are only examples for buttons, listboxes, and such. I can't find any mention of graphical capabilities such as drawing on a canvas (or in-memory bitmap), which are commonly found in other GUI libraries such as MFC or wxWidgets.

Does anyone know if the nana project can support graphical operations such as those underlying the VC++ `scribble` example? More specifically, the scribble example in MS visual studio's samples folder demonstrated drawing curves freehand in response to mouse events, storing the curves and refreshing a client area when the viewport undergoes zooming and panning (i.e. handling logical v.s.  image/pixel coordinate systems). These are the graphical API support I was looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: My question is to ask whether there is a specific function (drawing on canvas) in a specific c++ library, which is quite common and important. I showed what I have searched for so far. I don't believe this is only asking for a tutorial for some well-known functionality or request for a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find the examples at MS, and I'm not sure what you need. You could try with this links:

At docs: [drawing wrapper](http://nanapro.org/en-us/help/utilities/drawing.htm#) or [hier](https://github.com/qPCR4vir/nana-docs/wiki/Drawing), to set a drawing function.

At doxy-docs: [drawing](http://qpcr4vir.github.io/nana-docs/nana-doxy/d9/d46/classnana_1_1drawing.html)

The drawing functions can be constructed using: [graphics](http://qpcr4vir.github.io/nana-docs/nana-doxy/d6/d47/classnana_1_1paint_1_1graphics.html)

This way:

```
#include <nana/gui/wvl.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace nana;

    form fm;
    drawing dw(fm);
    dw.draw([](paint::graphics& graph)
    {
        graph.rectangle(rectangle{5, 5, 50, 50}, true, colors::red );
        graph.line(point(5, 5), point(55, 55), colors::white);
    });

    dw.update();
    fm.show();
    ::nana::exec();
}
```

[image]
Hope it helps

Comment: +1. Thanks. This is along the direction I was looking. MS visual studio had a scribble example in its samples folder. It shows how to draw curves freehand in response to mouse events, store the curves and refresh client area when the viewport undergoes zooming and panning (ie handling logical vs pixel coordinate systems).  These are the APIs I was looking for.

Comment: paint::graphics just provides a limited drawing functions, but by using GDI+, you will get rich drawing functions, see [FAQ](http://nanapro.org/en-us/help/faq.htm)